# Cocoa Pods .xcworkspace missing my project

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, swiftui, cocoapods

I've just started learning about CocoaPods today and I'm honestly very lost. In a tutorial, installing CocoaPods created a new .xcworkspace file, which had both their Pods and their original project. However, my new .xcworkspace file is missing all of my work from before (my app and code and previews etc). The project shows up in the file navigator, but I can't expand it or open it to access my work files.

In the screenshot below, you can see how there the ">" sign that signifies that I can dropdown the icon and open my files is there for the Pods project, but not my app project.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the rest of my actual app files into this .xcworkspace file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close all Xcode windows and then just open your workspace file, no other files that contain your project.

You can't have your project and a workspace with your project open at the same time.